# Memory Management - Virtual To Physical Address Translation

Tags: virtual-memory, paging

Please I need the correct way to convert Logical (Virtual) Address to Physical Address , i have the following Question :

Given the following Page Table :

[image]

Knowing that the virtual pages  and physical frame are 1 k Bytes, what is the memory address corresponding to each of the following virtual addresses encoded in hexadecimal: 142A and 0AF1?

i solved it like this , but i don't know if it is correct :

142A (hex)=5162(decimal)

5162/1024=5 (page number ) <----> Frame 1 in page table

5162mod1024=42 (Offset)

so the physical address corresponding to 142A = 1(physical)+42 (offset) or (1*1024+42)

so is that correct ?!

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

1Kbytes = 1024 bytes.  1024<sub>10</sub> = 0400<sub>16</sub>

- page 0 = 0000<sub>16</sub>, page 1 = 0400<sub>16</sub>, page 2 = 0800<sub>16</sub>, page 3 = 0C00<sub>16</sub>, page 4 = 1000<sub>16</sub>, page 5 = 1400<sub>16</sub>

  - So, 142A<sub>16</sub> is in page 5 ...
- Logical page 5 points to physical page 1.  Each page is 0400<sub>16</sub> bytes.  Physical page 1 starts at 0400<sub>16</sub> (page 0 would start at 0000<sub>16</sub>).
- 142A<sub>16</sub> is 2A<sub>16</sub> bytes past the start of page 5 at 1400<sub>16</sub> ...

  - so you add 2A<sub>16</sub> to the starting address of physical page 1 which is 0400<sub>16</sub>.  So logical address 142A<sub>16</sub> really is physical address 042A<sub>16</sub>.
  - Anything 1400<sub>16</sub> to 17FF<sub>16</sub> logically corresponds to 0400<sub>16</sub> to 07FF<sub>16</sub> physically, etc.

---

This is the type of table you could make to help you.  All based on multiples of 0400<sub>16</sub> since that is the page size.

```
Logical Page Number   Logical Page Address  ->  Physical Page Number   Physical Page Address
         0               0x0000 - 0x03FF                  4                0x1000 - 0x13FF                                                                            
         1               0x0400 - 0x07FF                  6                0x1800 - 0x1BFF                                                                            
         2               0x0800 - 0x0BFF                  8                0x2000 - 0x03FF                                                                            
         3               0x0C00 - 0x0FFF                  9                0x2400 - 0x27FF                                                                            
         4               0x1000 - 0x13FF                  12               0x3000 - 0x33FF                                                                            
         5               0x1400 - 0x17FF                  1                0x0400 - 0x07FF
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate for the great answer you made it more clear to me  , so my solution is right because decimal (1*1024+42 = 1066) in hexadecimal (042A)